# Javascript how to create a new object of a dictionary created in another file or a block in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Um trying to access the dictionary object from base_elem by creating a new object out of it and and trying to access the locale_rus()  method call from gridjs

How to accomplish this with OOP in javascript? um quite new to JS work 
I would share my implementation

```
                var lkl = {
                        'apple': 'apple',
                        'papaw': 'papaw'    
                }

                var base_elem = {
                    var dicttionary_object = new lkl();
                    console.log(lkl);
                    locale_rus: function(){
                        console.log('locale s');
                    }
                }

                var gridjs = {

                    elem: function(){
                        locale_rus();
                        console.log('Hello World!')
                    }
                }


                gridjs.__proto__ = base_elem
                gridjs.locale_rus();
```

it gives errors when trying to instantiate the dictionary object and when try to access the

> locale_rus()

method from the elem method

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. At least `var base_elem = {
                    var dicttionary_object = new lkl();`

Comment: Hi would like to know whats wrong there? @zerkms

Comment: Try to run it and see

Comment: to many syntax errors

Comment: Theres lots of syntax errors, run it open your browser console and it will tell you. You can't use the `new` keyword on an object. so `new lkl()` will throw an exception. `lkl` is an object not a method. I would strongly advise you look into `Object.create()` for building your objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

So essentially, we have the object lkl here which for some reason you want to clone. There are multiple ways to shallow clone an object. You can use jQuery.extend. I prefer [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which is a new feature from the ES6 spec.

The next step is to create our base_elem object which will be using as a prototype for GridJS function. We will describe the locale_rus function in the base object which will be inherited by all instances of the GridJS function.

We now define the GridJS function which holds a method to call the locale_rus method from the prototype.

Then we define the prototype for the GridJS object, instantiate an object using the new operator and invoke the elem and locale_rus methods which are both functional.

```js
var lkl = {
  'apple': 'apple',
  'papaw': 'papaw'    
};

var base_elem = {
  dicttionary_object :Object.assign({},lkl),
  
  locale_rus: function(){
    console.log('locale s');
    console.log(this.dicttionary_object);
  }
}


var GridJS = function(){

  this.elem = function(){
    this.locale_rus();

  }
}

GridJS.prototype = base_elem;

var gridjs = new GridJS();
gridjs.locale_rus();
gridjs.elem();
```

Comment: `Object.assign(lkl)` --- what's that?

Comment: @zerkms, [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), but i not sure why it need here :-)

Comment: OP wanted to clone lkl for some reason, so used it.

Comment: @Grundy now try to explain what exactly `Object.assign(lkl)` does.

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli does it clone it actually?

Comment: Yeah. Object.assign does a clone of all the enumerable props of a source object.

Comment: Well, now it does. My comments were addressing the previous version of the code that was incorrect, presumably.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add {} earlier. Corrected it.

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli Awesome , Thank you so much!

Comment: @zerkms, i'm so sloooow :-) _method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object._

Comment: I wish people would actually explain there answers in the answer not in a dozen comments. Also when they are advising ES6 things that the user may not be able to use yet.

Comment: @ste2425 indeed. What is more curious is that - as soon as you're allowed to use ES2015 features why not use its classes.

Comment: @zerkms, because classes is complex, and seems a bit complicated instead just call some function

Comment: @Anonymous0day, but why? :-)

Comment: @Grundy they are not at all. It's easier to deal with classes than to build a prototype inheritance *properly*.

Comment: @Grundy because people don't have their console opened eveytime, i want to see the result in the snippet result not in my debugger ! :-(

Comment: @Anonymous0day why dont you like console.log? have you ever tried vim or vi editor for JavaScript?

Comment: @Kalanamith ??? what are talking about ? just imagine i'am browsing this site with an Android mobile or Tablet or Apple mobile device / Tablet where is my console ??? can answer ???

Comment: @Anonymous0day the console is meant for debugging that is its purpose. Debugging to the DOM add's huge amounts of overhead to simply outputting a string, then what happens when you want to serialize and object? Don't know about you but when im debugging strange issue with a 100 element array i'd be very grateful for console instead of trawling through a huge string in the DOM. But it does depend on your platform. For desktop browsers there is no excuse not to use the console.

Comment: @ste2425 because you see how many `console.log` for  100 element array ??? most of time it is `console.log('blablabla')` !!!

Comment: @ste2425 i was not talking of veritable use of console.log i am talking of the useless case for login 1->10 lines !

Answer (score 0):

Traditional way of doing this is to assign the prototype through a constructor function or during the object creation process.

```
        //Two discreet objects
        var lkl = {
                'apple': 'apple',
                'papaw': 'papaw'    
        }

        var base_elem = {
            dicttionary_object: {},    

            locale_rus: function(){
               alert("test");
            }
        }    


        //Create a new one based on another
        var gridjs = Object.create(base_elem);


        //Create another object as a property of another object 
        gridjs.dicttionary_object = Object.create(lkl);


        //Now test them
        gridjs.locale_rus();
        alert(gridjs.dicttionary_object);
```